# Metal sampler filtering options

Tags: filtering, metal, sampling

In the example below, does it mean that all filtering options (mag_filter, min_filter, ...) are set to linear? I can't find anything in documentation for just "filter".

```
constexpr sampler textureSampler (filter::linear, address::clamp_to_edge, coord::pixel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. It fills `min_filter` and `mag_filter`, but not `mip_filter`. It's very unfortunate that it's not documented. However, you can go into `metal_texture` header from Xcode, and you will see

```
constexpr METAL_FUNC _sampler_state _build_sampler_state(_sampler_state s, filter flt)
{
  return
  {
    s.s_address_v, s.t_address_v, s.r_address_v,
        static_cast<uchar>(flt), static_cast<uchar>(flt), s.mip_filter_v,
        s.coord_v, s.compare_func_v,
        s.max_anisotropy_v, s.lod_clamp_min_v, s.lod_clamp_max_v,
        s.border_color_v, s.reduction_v,
  };
}
```

and if you check out `_sampler_state`

```
struct _sampler_state
{
  uchar s_address_v;
  uchar t_address_v;
  uchar r_address_v;
  uchar mag_filter_v;
  uchar min_filter_v;
  uchar mip_filter_v;
  uchar coord_v;
  uchar compare_func_v;
  uchar max_anisotropy_v;
  float lod_clamp_min_v;
  float lod_clamp_max_v;
  uchar border_color_v;
  uchar reduction_v;
};
```

so you can see that it will set `static_cast<uchar>(flt)` in the `mag_filter_v`, and `min_filter_v`.

I think the `mip_filter` is conceptually different enough that it can't be set with those.